# Integral of $x^2\cos^n x$ over $[-\pi,\pi]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, special-functions

Is there a closed form (or in terms of some special functions) of the following definite integral? 
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}x^2\cos^nx~\mathrm{d}x$$

where $\cos^nx$ is the $n-$th power of cosine, and $n$ is a positive integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Too long for a comment.*

I suppose that this would be given in terms of some hypergeometric functions.

However, having a look at *"Table of Integrals, Series, and Products"* (seventh edition) by I.S. Gradshteyn and I.M. Ryzhik, at the bottom of page 214, there is an interesting recurrence relation for the antideivative
$$\int x^m\cos^n(x)\,dx=\frac{x^{m-1} \cos ^{n-1}(x) (m \cos (x)+n x \sin (x))}{n^2} +\frac{(n-1)}n\int x^m \cos ^{n-2}(x)\,dx-$$ $$\frac{m(m-1)  }{n^2}\int x^{m-2} \cos ^n(x)\,dx$$

Applied to $m=2$, this would give
$$I_n=(-1)^n\frac{4 \pi  }{n^2}-\frac{2 \sqrt{\pi } \left(1+(-1)^n\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{n^2\,
   \Gamma \left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)}+\frac{n-1}n I_{n-2}$$ with $I_0= \frac{2 \pi ^3}{3}$ and $I_1= -4\pi$.

This means that
$$I_{2n}=\frac{\pi }{n^2}-\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\, \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{n^3 \Gamma
   (n)}+\frac{2n-1}{2n} I_{2n-2}$$
$$I_{2n+1}=-\frac{4 \pi }{(2 n+1)^2}+\frac{2n}{2n+1} I_{2n-1}$$

**Edit**

In terms of hypergoemetric functions, at least
$$I_{2n+1}=-\frac{\pi \, 2^{1-2 m}}{(2 m+1)^2}\,\,\, _3F_2\left(-2
   m-1,-m-\frac{1}{2},-m-\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2}-m,\frac{1}{2}-m;-1\right)$$

Comment: Thank you, Claude!

Comment: @user31899. You are very welcome ! I am sorry to have been unable to find the hypergeometric function for $I_{2n}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Using the complex representation and the binomial development,

$$x^2(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})^n=x^2\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nke^{ikx}e^{-i(n-k)x}=x^2\sum\binom nke^{i(2k-n)x}.$$

If $n$ is even, the central term in the summation is a constant, and it can be handled separately.

Then if you integrate by parts on the exponentials, the new integral to be considered is
$$2x\sum\binom nk\frac{e^{i(2k-n)x}}{i(2k-n)}.$$
After a second integration by parts, you get the integrand

$$2\sum\binom nk\frac{e^{i(2k-n)x}}{i(2k-n)^2},$$

of which an antiderivative is

$$2\sum\binom nk\frac{e^{i(2k-n)x}}{i(2k-n)^3}.$$

For arguments $x=\pm\pi$, the exponentials reduce to $\pm1$, and the final integral will be a linear combination of powers of $\pi$ (up to the third) with rational coefficients that are finite sums of weighted binomial coefficients.

I would be surprised if there was an easy closed-form.

Answer (score 0):

For odd $n$,
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi x^2 \cos^n x \,dx =
\sum_{k = 0}^n \int_{-\pi}^\pi
 x^2 \,2^{-n} \binom n k e^{i k x} e^{-i (n - k) x} dx =
\sum_{k = 0}^n \frac {(-1)^n 2^{2 - n} \pi \binom n k} {(n - 2k)^2} = \\
\frac {(-1)^n 2^{2 - n} \pi} {n^2} \,{_3F_2} \!\left(
 -n, -\frac n 2, -\frac n 2; 1 - \frac n 2, 1 - \frac n 2; -1 \right).$$
For $n = 2m$,
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi x^2 \cos^n x dx =
\sum_{k = 0 \atop k \neq m}^{2m}
  \frac {2^{2 - 2m} \pi \binom {2m} k} {(2m - 2k)^2} +
\frac {2^{1 - 2m} \pi^3 \binom {2m} m} 3 = \\
\frac {\sqrt \pi \,\Gamma \!\left( \frac {n + 1} 2 \right)}
  {3 \Gamma \!\left( \frac n 2 + 2 \right)} \left(
 3n \,{_4F_3} \!\left( 1, 1, 1, 1 - \frac n 2; 2, 2, 2 + \frac n 2; -1 \right) +
  \pi^2 (n + 2) \right).$$